# Character limit Trying to modify the system PATH variable after already entered the long path in register give error msg

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path

Getting this error in windows 10 64 bit
I did enable to enter long size path from the registry
My question is how to disable this character limitation ?

[image]

I most say that this limitation is happening after i run the command :
setx /M PATH "C:\dev\my\java\jvm\graalvm-community-jdk-21.0.1_windows-x64_bin\graalvm-openjdk-21.0.1+12.1\bin;%PATH%"
it reset my all path and started to show this popup ..

Comment: Your path is too long. What you can do is use mklink in a cmd prompt with administrative privileges, to link your bin path to a subfolder of c:\dev. `mklink -j c:\dev\bin c:\dev\my\java\jvm\graalvm-community-jdk-21.0.1_windows-x64_bin\graalvm-openjdk-21.01.1+12.1\bin`, and then adding c:\dev\bin to your path instead. Don't forget to update your junction if you update your install.

Comment: In addition to what @LPChip suggests.  Clean up your path.  You don't need all of the stuff in it that is there (I guarantee it).  I don't know exactly to what extent, but that path needs to get searched OVER AND OVER and it will indeed cost speed.

Comment: all good , but the main question is how to setup the path to be accepting more then 2047 chars